# Conexion a base de datos por medio de diferentes maquinas

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, windows-forms

Estoy apunto de finalizar mi proyecto solo que he estado trabajando en una maquina virtual, ahi se mantendra la base de datos en  SQL Server accedia mediante aunteticacion de windows pero la aplicacion de escritorio se instalara en 5 maquinas diferentes dentro del negocio, como debo cambiar mi linea de codigo? debo crear un usuario especifico para las maquinas? Aqui abajo mi codigo

```
  public SqlConnection CrearConexion()
    {
        SqlConnection Cadena = new SqlConnection();
        try
        {
            Cadena.ConnectionString = "Server= MXNEGOCIO01" + ";Database= ProyectoNEGOCIO " + ";Trusted_Connection=True";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Cadena = null;
            throw ex;
        }
        return Cadena;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si todas las PCs estan en la misma red bajo el mismo dominio de windows puede seguir aplicando seguridad integrada para autenticarte

Ahora bien, si vas a tener que configurar el `Sql Server` para permitir conexiones remotas ya que por defecto solo permite locales

[How to configure remote access and connect to a remote SQL Server instance](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/)

Valida que tengas marcada la opcion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero tambien revisa que este habilitado el `puerto TCP`

[Cómo conectarse a un SQL Server remoto](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/como-conectarse-a-un-sql-server-remoto/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y que el `firewall de windows` no este bloqueando la conexion

Mas alla de la seguridad con la cual te autenticas debes validar que permiten las conexiones remotas

Answer (score 1):

Debes habilitar la autenticación via SQL en tu instancia. crea un login y un usuario en SQL y lo pones en la cadena de conexión, quitas el trusted_conexion y pones user id = tu_usuario; password = password, al colocarlo en la cadena de conexión podría utilizar un solo usuario para todas las conexiones.

Para mayor referencia consulta el siguiente sitio, muy útil.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/kb/

Y una recomendación extra, quita el throw del catch, el throw dispara errores que el catch debe atrapar, no generar, recomiendo un MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) en su lugar.

Saludos.

Comment: en otros foros vi algo sobre sacar la ip de la maquina donde almacenara la bas de datos aqui es necesario?

Comment: No, no es necesario, siempre colocar el nombre de la instancia yo en particular coloco 'cstring = "Data Source = servidor\instancia; initial catalog = nombrebd; user id = user; password=password', la ip que mencionas iría en el "servidor"